# In MonoDevelop, how do I include all assemblies from a package as references?

Tags: mono, assemblies, reference, monodevelop

I want to include all the assemblies in the GtkSharp package. Right now, I have to find every assembly and include it individually. Is there any way to simple include all assemblies in the GtkSharp package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, though if you use the GTK# designer it will automatically add several GTK#-related references.